# R reads in wrong file

Tags: excel

I'm very stuck here, any suggestions appreciated.

I'm writing an R package in RStudio which procceses a lot of data inside `./data-raw/`. I have multiple sequential folders with the same `.xls` file named in each, e.g. `Table 1.xls`.

I wrote a loop that generates the required path + file name, and then reads the excel in with `read.xlsx` from the `xlsx` package (but I've tested this with `read_excel` from the `readxl` package as well with the same result).

The file exists, the path is spelt correctly, I'm in the correct working directory (I've also tried this manually by auto-completing the file in RStudio).  And yet it reads in the wrong file after a few iterations.

```
processedData = list()
for(i in 1:10){
  fileName = paste("./AB-",i,"/Table 1.xls",sep="")
  data = read.xlsx(fileName,sheetIndex = 1)
  
  # Then I have a section that processes the data
  # **************
  boop = ...

  # And then I save that data
  processedData[[i]] = boop
}
```

There are no error messages, it simply loads the wrong file.

I'm at a loss.

#### Update

It's just a single file.
If I open it through file explorer (I'm on Windows 10) or RStudio's file pane it opens what I expect.
If I open it through R or RStudio it opens a different file.

#### Update 2

If I delete the file that I want to open, it can't open anything (good!).
But if I keep the file I want to open, but delete the file that it does in fact read in... it still manages to read in the file that I've deleted!

### Solved

Apparently there was a hidden sheet in the Excel file, which happened to also be a file in a different directory. -_-

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not know your folder structure we cannot be sure this fixes all of your issues but you overwrite `data` every iteration. Use a list to store your data files and proceed

```
data_list <- list()

for(i in 1:10){
  fileName = paste("./AB-",i,"/Table 1.xls",sep="")
  data_list[[i]] = read.xlsx(fileName,sheetIndex = 1)
}
```